# How do I update a SessionAttribute asynchronously?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, asynchronous

Using Spring Session with HttpSession and SpringMVC how do I update the value of a SessionAttribute from a different thread that is invoked via an @Async annotated method?

The use case I have is I want to receive a callback from a service like Stripe or PayPal say `/callback?code=foo`, so I have something like

```
@GetMapping(path = "/calback")
public Object paymentCallback(
  @RequestParam("code") String code,
  @SessionAttribute MyFormData formData) {

  formData.setPaid(codeIsLegit(true));
  submitter.submitAsync(formData);

  return "processing";
}
```

Processing is a Spring template that simply loops around itself until the form data is updated

```java
@GetMapping(path = "/processing")
public Object processingLoop(
  @SessionAttribute MyFormData formData) {

  if (formData.isUserCreated()) {
    return new RedirectView("success");
  } else {
    formData.incrementLoop();
  }
  return "processing";
}
```

For my submitter I have a method

```
@Async
public void submitAsync(MyFormData formData) {
  submit(formData); // original synced submit method
}
```

So I got as far as that where the form was submitted, the processing is done so the user is created, but now I want to update `MyFormData` in the session to contain that the user was created.